# как обновить postcss до 8.2.10 версии?

Tags: ubuntu, npm

```
sudo npm install npm -g  обновило до 7.15.1
 а требует jetstream 8.2.10
```

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Npm версии 8 ещё не существует

Comment: вот на это дает ссылку https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1693

Comment: Так это не про npm, а про postcss

Comment: @Alexey Ten как его обновить?

Comment: Ну наверное `npm install postcss@8`